# sending variables into another script

Tags: php

how to send the variable of **$sum** into another script? i tried **$_SESSION** but i never get the variables in the other script i like to make it a **$_POST** but never get the result too

```
if($num==15){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  "<td>totaltime";
     echo"<td><center> ".$sum."</center></td>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

<form method = "POST" action="salary.php">
Total min:<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php $sum;?>" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE">
</form>
```

Comment: For one, the code you provided isn't valid (because you never exit PHP). Not sure if that's just a copy/paste issue though. As for your problem, storing them in a session is probably the best bet - you'll need to call `session_start);` on *both* pages at the very top of the script though. Then you can do `$_SESSION['sum] = $sum;` in your first page, and in your second page you can do `Echo "Sum is: ".$_SESSION['sum'];`

Comment: im using the $_SESSION where im gonna put that? outside of if statement? or inside of it?

Comment: Where do you define (set the value of) `$sum`? @user3793272

Comment: Also, in your code, within the form, you have `<?php $sum;?>` -- this doesn't do anything, you need to `echo` the variable.

Comment: @Qirel i just cut it from my codes if i post it it will fill an unnecessary codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your  first code, you can define `$sum` to be the value of a SESSION. What's important when dealing with sessions, is that `session_start();` has to be **the very first thing** called in your script. Before any HTML, any output.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ($num==15) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<td>totaltime";
    echo "<td><center> ".$sum."</center></td>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $_SESSION['sum'] = $sum;
}
?>
```

In your second page, you check if the sum has been set, and then you can echo it. Otherwise, because you define the `$_SESSION['sum'] = $sum;` within an `if`-statement, you can get *Undefined variable* notices.

In your second page

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['sum'])) {
    echo "The sum is: ".$_SESSION['sum'];
} else {
    echo "The sum-variable has not been set";
}
?>
```

You can access this variable from all your scripts and pages, as long as you call `session_start();` on top of the script. It will be removed when the browser is closed and temporary files are deleted from the cache.

Comment: thank you sir but can i make it a `$_POST` i dont know the syntax of it without a form just inside of the _php_

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you want to make it a `$_POST`? Why? In that case, see the example in the other answer - because you'll have to do it via a form in that case.

Comment: ok nvm ill stick with session thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

if ($num == 15) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<td>totaltime";
    echo"<td><center> " . $sum . "</center></td>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
<form method = "POST" action="salary.php">
    Total min:<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $sum; ?>" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE">
</form>
```

**salary.php**

```
<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>
```

Comment: thanks sir it does answer my question but can i make it a without form solution **$_POST**?